# tried to crosscompile linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, gnu-make, ld

I tried to make it with

```
make ARCH="aarch64" CC="aarch64-alpine-linux-musl-" CROSS_COMPILE="aarch64-alpine-linux-musl-gcc" HOSTCC="gcc" LDFLAGS="--allow-multiple-definition" HOSTLDFLAGS="--allow-multiple-definition" HOSTCFLAGS=""
```

and I got strange error

```
HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '--allow-multiple-definition'
```

that's weird because I never passed flags with HOSTCCFLAGS

Comment: `gcc` is often invoked as a linker too. You don't really need to set `HOSTxxx` options though.

Comment: so what can I do to allow multiple definition?

Comment: Your `CC` and `CROSS_COMPILE` values seem to be swapped over.